# jQuery post to another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

If I have a Controller called "HomeController" and I'm on the Index page of that controller, how can I do a jQuery Ajax post to another controller.

I tried the below,

```
    $.post("/DetailedQuote/jQueryGetDetailedQuote", { productCode: "LPJ" }, function(newHTML) {
        alert(88);
    });
```

I have a `DetailedQuoteController`.

I have also tried;

```
post("DetailedQuote/
post("DetailedQuote.aspx/
post("/DetailedQuote.aspx/
post("/DetailedQuoteController/
post("DetailedQuoteController/
post("DetailedQuoteController.aspx/
post("/DetailedQuoteController.aspx/
```

And still no joy.

I should also mention that this is running a Hybrid WebForms and MVC site on IIS 6.

**EDIT**

The error that is being returned in error: is "error" so I assume that's maybe a 404.

In fact, it is a 404.  I just checked.

Comment: [What error did you get?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/21/9999675.aspx)

Comment: No error but no post back either.

Comment: Look in Firebug or Fiddler and check the server's response.

Comment: Then what are you asking now?

Comment: Still the same question.  If the controller exists why can I not get to it?  Why is there a 404 error and what might be the url i need to use in the ajax call.

Comment: Please show us your controller, action, and route table.

Comment: The route table is the default on and the controller only holds the actionresult as a stub.  there are no parameters etc.  it's as vanilla as you can get at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class DetailedQuoteController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetDetailedQuote(string productCode)
    {
        return Json(new { Code = productCode, Quote = 123 });
    }
}
```

And to invoke it first declare a global javascript variable containing the address of this controller somewhere inside the view:

```
var quoteAddress = '<%= Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "DetailedQuote", action = "GetDetailedQuote" }) %>';
```

And finally call the method:

```
$(function() {
    $.post(quoteAddress, { productCode: 'LPJ' }, function(json) {
        alert(json.Quote);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your jQuery command, so the most obvious place to start looking is in the controller itself.  Things to check would be:

- Does your Controller action return a Json response (e.g. `public JsonResult jQueryGetDetailedQuote`)?
- Are you using the `Json()` method to return your object?
- Do you have your action decorated with the [HttpPost] attribute?

Perhaps you could post part of your controller code as well?

I notice that in your jQuery method you're calling an action called jQueryGetDetailedQuote.  If your intention is purely to just GET a result, then perhaps you should use jQuery's `$.get()` or `$.getJSON()` functions instead?

Comment: @Phil, thanks for the reply.  At present the controller code is empty other than the method stub.  I can happily post to a method in the same controller that the page is being served from but not to another.  I suspect it might have something to do with IIS 6